# ReferenceError: "$" is not defined in Client Side?

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Apps Scripts, I'm trying to use jQuery in the Templating HTML. I'm receiving the following error:

> ReferenceError: "$" is not defined.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  My favorite Google products:
  <? var data = ['Gmail', 'Docs', 'Android']; ?>
  <? $(data).each(function(){ ?>
    <?= this ?>
  <?}); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate();
}
```

Comment: In my case .. I had wrongly included the jQuery library in my script

Answer (score 2):

Tag `<?` that means the code runs on the server, and the server side it seems jQuery is not loaded, so the $ reference does not exist.

Something like this should work without problem:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(function() {
          var data = ['Gmail', 'Docs', 'Android'];
          var products = $('#products');
          $(data).each(function(index, value) {
             products.append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
          });
       });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>    
  My favorite Google products:
  <ul id="products"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After understanding the code should be applied as recommended in Html Service: Best Practices - 'Load data asynchronously, not in templates' https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-best-practices?hl=es#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates